# SQL Simple Case Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case

This simple SQL statement seems to be returning the wrong answer. Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong. I'm using MySQL Workbench.

I create and populate the table with the following commands:

```
drop table if exists TRIANGLES;
create table TRIANGLES(A int, B int, C int);
insert into TRIANGLES values(20,20,23);
insert into TRIANGLES values(20,20,20);
insert into TRIANGLES values(20,21,22);
insert into TRIANGLES values(13,14,30);
```

and I execute my triangle type query as:

```
select (case
when A+B<=C then 'Not a Triangle'
when B+C<=A then 'Not a Triangle'
when A+C<=B then 'Not a Triangle'
when A=B=C then 'Equilateral'
when A=B and B!=C then 'Isoscelus'
when B=C and C!=A then 'Isoscelus'
when A=C and B!=C then 'Isoscelus'
when A!=B!=C then 'Scalene'
end) as typ from TRIANGLES;
```

but the answer I get is:

```
Isoscelus
Scalene -- bad result
Scalene
Not a Triangle
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hello! What's the expected answer?

Comment: row 2 is the only incorrect one? try changing it to when a=b and b=c.

Comment: Good question. I don't understand why MySQL even accepts the syntax `A=B=C`.

Comment: Problem is that you are checking a inconvenient logic using '=' operator. Use A=B and B=C instead of  A=B=C in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `A=B=C` use `A=B and B=C`:

```
select *, (case
when A+B<=C then 'Not a Triangle'
when B+C<=A then 'Not a Triangle'
when A+C<=B then 'Not a Triangle'
when A=B and b=C then 'Equilateral'
when A=B and B!=C then 'Isoscelus'
when B=C and C!=A then 'Isoscelus'
when A=C and B!=C then 'Isoscelus'
when A!=B and B!=C and A!=C then 'Scalene' -- or just use: ELSE 'Scalene'
end) as typ 
from TRIANGLES;
```

Result:

```
A            B            C            typ             
-------------------------------------------------------
20           20           23           Isoscelus       
20           20           20           Equilateral     
20           21           22           Scalene         
13           14           30           Not a Triangle
```

Comment: Interesting...should the inequality also be A!=B and B!=C and A!=C instead of A!=B!=C?

Comment: Yes, of course. Fixed. Chained operators can be used, but you'll use them 99% of the time the wrong way.